# How to pass a certain amount of data when clicking a link in html?

Tags: java, html, jsp

How can I pass a specific set of data when I click a link? 
for example

```
<a href="1.jsp">1</a>
<a href="2.jsp">2</a>
```

I want to pass 1 for clicking 1 and pass 2 for clicking 2.
How can I do this ?

Comment: `<a href="1.jsp?value=1">1</a>`...

Comment: Now I have an clear idea, to extract the data can I use: request.getParameter("value");

Answer (score 0):

You can encode arbitrary parameters with the following syntax:

```
<a href="1.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2&...&paramN=valueN">1</a>
```

If you are using servlets, you can then access user request's parameter by:

```
String value1 = request.getParameter("param1");
```

All parameters will be strings.